# Sharing a transaction between EF DbContext in separated projects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, integration-testing, xunit

What I want to do is to write some integration tests for a micro service environment using Entity Framework in which I need to isolate every tests scenario's transaction so that tests would not affect each other in terms of manipulating a database.

Then, after the tests are ran I want to check the database to see if the work is done correctly.

What I did so far is to create two base classes as followed. (I am using xunit as the testing framework)

```
public class DatabaseInitializer : IDisposable
{
    public readonly MyContext DatabaseContext;

    public DatabaseInitializer()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        var configuration = builder.Build();
        DatabaseContext = new MyContext(configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlConnectionString"));
        DatabaseContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        DatabaseContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    }
}

public class TransactionIsolator : IClassFixture<DatabaseInitializer> , IDisposable
{
    protected readonly TransactionScope TransactionScope;
    protected readonly MyContext DatabaseContext;

    public TransactionIsolator(DatabaseInitializer dbInitializer)
    {
        DatabaseContext = dbInitializer.DatabaseContext;
        TransactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        TransactionScope.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Here, the first (`DatabaseInitializer`) will ensure that the needed database is created at the first of test suite running and then deletes it upon its disposal.

The second class, will then create a transaction and rolls back the changes when the test is done. So when I write two tests like the followings it will correctly isolate my access to database for each test case running.

```
public class ExampleTests : TransactionIsolator
{
    public ExampleTests(DatabaseInitializer dbInitializer) : base(dbInitializer)
    {
    }

    [Fact]
    void example_test()
    {
        DatabaseContext.Indexes.Should().BeEmpty();
        DatabaseContext.Indexes.Add(new Indexes {PublisherId = "123", LastIndex = new byte[] {0x12, 0x13}});
        DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
        DatabaseContext.Indexes.Should().NotBeEmpty();
    }

    [Fact]
    void example_test_2()
    {
        DatabaseContext.Indexes.Should().BeEmpty();
        DatabaseContext.Indexes.Add(new Indexes {PublisherId = "321", LastIndex = new byte[] {0x12, 0x13}});
        DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
        DatabaseContext.Indexes.Should().NotBeEmpty();
    }
}
```

These will be passed and all is good EXCEPT I do not have any access to micro services to set their transaction or at least I don't have any idea whether if it is even possible or not. I mean this would be very awesome if I could configure or signal a micro service to use a transaction for its DB from outside of the scope of that application.

That aside, if it is not possible, what can you suggest to use in this situation I want to gain isolation for each test scenario and still be able to run them is parallel.

Comment: You might want to look at UnitOfWork pattern.

Comment: can you elaborate? I don't see how this pattern will help me isolate a multi processed system access  to the database. Note that I want to isolate the access through a test scenario running only, meaning that in a test scenario, a service's write should be accessible in another service's read.

Answer (score 0):

For most providers this "just works".  TransactionScope sets the static property [Transaction.Current](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transaction.current?view=netframework-4.7.2), and ADO.Net Providers can (and typically do) Enlist in the ambient transaction.  See: [Implementing an Implicit Transaction using Transaction Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-an-implicit-transaction-using-transaction-scope)

And at least for SQL Server, if your tests use the same connection string, and don't run concurrently, they will *also* use the same SqlConnection and not require promotion to a Distributed Transaction.  As the SQLClient Connection Pool is partitioned by Transaction, and a subsequent request to the pool for the same (ConnectionString,Transaction) will use the same SqlConnection.

Note also for SQL Server that there are some initialization operations that can't be performed inside a transaction.  You can't create or alter a database in a transaction.  But you can create tables and indexes *inside* a database in a transaction.  Other platforms have different restrictions.  Oracle, for instance, automatically commits DDL statements.

Comment: Reading your answer and some other documents I now know that my problem can be solved using a distributed transaction (I want to test my scenarios concurrently) I have tested it in sql server but I don't have any idea how to enforce a transaction to be distributed in ef, also how can I set the name of that transaction so that I can share it across services? It is straight forward in sql server but in ef it is not that obvious

Comment: EF is layered on top of the ADO.NET SqlClient, so this should just work.

Comment: Actually no, I think I misunderstood distributed transactions. They are designed to have transactions on multiple servers to be synced on a single client. What I want is to have multiple clients to have a single transaction synced on a single server. So no this will not solve my problem.

Comment: Just test it.  If your methods use the same connection string and don’t use multiple connections at the same time then they will share a single SQL Server transaction.  If the use different connection strings, or multiple concurrent connections, then they will share a single Distributed transaction.